# Paypal Sandbox 2014 Non US test account Sign Up proper link

Tags: paypal

Ok I had a Paypal Sandbox account a year ago. I am developing a new site for a client and when I try to Login it won't recognize my email address. I tried forgot my password > forgot password still nothing. So I guessed that maybe due to inactivity for such a long time they may have deleted my account. So then I try to Sign Up for a new one. I entered my details 3 times now and spent 6 hours trying to figure out what is the proper link to do this. Then I went to another Sandbox link which required me to entered a US Zip code and its a dead end. I am not even sure which Paypal account I signed up for those three times. No email nothing at all.

I am a Non US developer and the FAQ link for Non US developers just points to their REST API. Can someone please guide me to the proper Paypal Sandbox Setup for Non US developers including  the proper sign up links please. And I know Stackoverflow does not like rants but from my experience dealing with Paypal, GTA 6 should make a satirical Paypal company in their next Game with Paypal Developer Rampage mode for the main protagonist who also happens to be a Developer.

**EDIT: REST API does not include UK :(**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1st, here is a link to the International Developer page (I tested it 1st to be sure it's a live link):

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/faq/#international-developer-questions

The developer site has been redesigned recently; you now sign in with the same credentials you use to sign into your PayPal Business account. Once you log in, import your existing Sandbox test accounts using the email address and password you used previously with the Sandbox. You can import only once. Please make sure you import to the PayPal account that you want to use for development.